# XPath testing dates

Tags: vb.net, xpath

I've hunted high and low and found some very interesting functionality with XPATH but, I haven't found a way to test DATES.

I have a Date attribute that I want to use to fetch a collection of nodes.

```
<History>
        <item>
          <Name>string</Name>
          <Location>string</Location>
          <VisitDate>01/08/2013</VisitDate>
          <Description>string</Description>
        </item>
</History>
```

The XPath code happily finds an equals, but I need to perform a => test.

```
Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument
doc.Load(filename)
Dim d As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Today)
s = "//History/item[VisitDate=>'" & d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "']"
Dim nodes As Xml.XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes(s)
```

Now this doesn't work. It errors out at the `SelectNodes(s)`, so it obviously doesn't like the ">" bit.

Are there any "Date" functions in XPath, I've found `boolean()`; `concat()`; `true()`; `not true()`; `translate()`; `substring()` etc, and I'm presuming that I'm going to eventually have to use a combination of these, and maybe others, but I can't figure out how to do "greater than"....

Is there anyone out there with an understanding of XPath in this area?

Answer (score 1):

I've always found that the easiest way to compare dates in XPath is to convert them to integers of the form YYYYMMDD, i.e. standard XML date format but with the hyphens removed.

You end up with an effective comparison of the following:

```
translate('2013-08-01', '-', '') > 20130824
```

It's a shame that your dates are stored as DD/MM/YYYY rather than YYYY-MM-DD as it means you'll have to do some work with `substring()` to reorganise the values, but it should be easy enough.

Comment: I can't format this, and I can't "Answer" so forgive the difficulty in reading this --------- So, would be following be a logical solution? --------- 

Dim d As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2, Today) --------- 
s = "//History/item[translate(substring(VisitDate,1,string-length(substring-before(VisitDate, ' '))), '-', '') > " & d.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "']" --------- I've changed all the dates to --------- <VisitDate>yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm</VisitDate> --------- 

in the XML as you suggested. I've also changed the DateAdd to -2 so that I can do a ">"

Comment: Well, apart from the stray single quote before my ], this works!  YES!  Thanks so much, to everyone...

Answer (score 0):

XPath 2.0 has much better date and time handling capability than XPath 1.0. The native XPath processor in .NET only supports XPath 1.0, but support for 2.0 is available in at least two third-party products that run under .NET: Saxon (my product) and XmlPrime.

XPath 2.0 still requires dates to be in ISO format `yyyy-mm-dd`, but its easy enough to transform to this from `dd/mm/yyyy`, for example using regular expressions.

Comment: Where can I find XPath 2.0?